# Separable variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was asked if the equation $y' = x + y$ was of separable variables. The way i tried to solve this, was supposing that $x + y = g(y).f(x)$, and then i differentiated with respect to $x$ and to $y$. My doubt is if it is possible to assume that $y$ does dot depend on $x$, such that when i differentiate the equation with respect to x, i would have $1 = f'(x)g(y)$, instead of $1 = f'(x)g(y) + f(x)g'(y)y'$

Comment: This is not a homogeneous equation. But the corresponding homogeneous one is separable. In your approach you should use partial derivatives, but I don’t think this will give you the answer. Since $f’(x) = 1/g(y)$, $g(y) = const$, but this is absurd.

Answer (score 1):

You can make this separable by doing the following:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
& \text{Let } u = x + y \\
& \text{then } \frac{du}{dx} = 1 + \frac{dy}{dx} = 1 + u 
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
So, you have:
\begin{equation*}
\frac{du}{dx} = 1 + u 
\end{equation*}
Which has the stacionary solution for $u(x) = -1$ and the general solution:
\begin{equation*}
\frac{1}{1+u}du = 1dx \Leftrightarrow ln|1+u| = x + C, C \in \mathbb{R} 
\end{equation*}
Going back to y-variable you get:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
y_{1}(t) = -(1+x) \\[10pt]
ln|1+x+y| = x + C, C \in \mathbb{R}
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
So, conclusion: this isn't a separable equation, but can be reduced to one using that variable change $u = x+y$

Answer (score 0):

You can make this separable by replicating the right side on the left,
$$
(y+x)'=y+x+1\\
(y+x+1)'=y+x+1
$$
so that with $u(x)=y(x)+x+1$ you get the easily separable $u'=u$.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the equation as $y'=f(x)+ g(y)$ where both $f,g$ are functions in one variable. So it's a separable equation: we can separate the variables $x,y$ into separate parts. So yes, it is. It's linear and separable.